# Which programming languages are used in the Star Trek universe?

Tags: star-trek, computers

In the *Star Trek* franchise, a number of characters "reprogram a computer" or "write a holodeck program" or do similar sorts of programming. Has is ever been identified what sort of languages are in use in this universe?

Comment: They use [Logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)).. You know you can move that turtle in 3D space..

Comment: Why bother "writing" anything when you can just tell the computer to "install a recursive algorithm" instead?

Comment: Klingon On Rails, lol, Well I saw some screens with pseudo C++ code

Comment: I'm not sure what they use on the ships, but at least half the legacy codebase of civilian infrastructure will be COBOL.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### C++

No, seriously, they still use [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++). Heck, they're even still doing their own memory management!

In *Star Trek: Discovery* 1x03 "[Context is for Kings](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Context_Is_for_Kings_(episode))", Stamets asks Burnham to "reconcile these two pieces of code". When she later shows the location where the error is, it's clearly C++, or something remarkably similar to it.

[image: Star Trek: Discovery uses C++ code]

Here are the last few lines of the code:

```
LPVOID _stdcall VirtualAlloc(LPVOID ipAddress, SIZE_T dwSize, flAllocationType, DWORD flProtect);
HANDLE _stdcall CreateMutexW(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES ipMutexAttributes, BOOL bInitialOwner; LPCWSTR ipName);
UINT _stcall SetErrorMode(UINT uMode);
BOOL _stdcall FreeLibrary(HMODULE hLibModule);
```

[VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [CreateMutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx) (but not CreateMutexW), [SetErrorMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [FreeLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are all part of C++ recognized by Microsoft Windows in our time.

<sub>And yeah, you could probably argue that this C++ is placeholder for just "really complex-looking code", but given that Burnham debugging this specific piece of code is a plot point in the episode, I'm going to count it.</sub>

---

Thanks to [Jules](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/18944/jules) in the comments for finding the source of this code!

> .. interestingly, that code appears to be the real-world source code for the standard Windows system component, `kernel32.dll`. Or a very near replica of it. Possibly an automated reverse engineering of it, given the poor choice of variable names.
>
> The function that's shown in full (rather than just as a header) is [`GetCurrentProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx) -- the windows documentation for that shows that it is part of kernel32.dll. [Wikipedia comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#KERNEL32.DLL) that kernel32.dll mostly just delegates functionality to ntdll.dll, which you can see is exactly what the code shown is doing: it loads a reference to ntdll.dll, finds a pointer to a function from it, then calls it.

So apparently, they're still using Microsoft Windows in the 23rd Century and bugs are preventing Starfleet's science division from getting any work done! So much for Gene Roddenbery's dream of a utopic future!

Comment: It's C+++ in the 22nd century...

Comment: There's a difference of two centuries between question and your answer. During the time of Discovery, Holodeck didn't even exist.

Comment: @Bat I meant the Star Trek franchise, not a particular show. Plus, Episode 6 shows that Discovery pretty much has their own holodeck #DiscoveryBreaksContinuity

Comment: Are we sure that Discovery is part of the canon? It’s very likely non-canon. Just look at the Klingons, for Pete’s sake.

Comment: @HamSandwich [Wikipedia says it's canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_canon). I think the explanation that the showrunners gave is that [Klingons have all sorts of appearances](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/klingon_evolution.htm) and that this is just a subgroup of Klingons we haven't seen before. Whether you are satisfied with that or not is up to you, but it's just as canon as every other TV show is.

Comment: But it’s so ridiculous.

Comment: If you actually meant the entire Star Trek franchise, then it's clear that the programming language used in the TNG era is any natural language that can be translated by the universal translator. We've witnessed hundreds of programs and other one-off instructions created and modified simply by speaking to the computer.

Comment: The difference is that the code shown is 99% commented out, but Trek AI computers are able to read the comments and just do what the programmer really wanted.

Comment: Anyway by the time of TOS they'd progressed to programming computers by just plugging the correct colored block of jello into a slot.

Comment: @Bat - Holodecks absolutely existed by the time of Discovery if this is prime universe. Do you mean "Federation" holodecks? http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Unexpected_(episode), http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Practical_Joker_(episode)

Comment: ... interestingly, that code appears to be the real-world source code for the standard Windows system component, `kernel32.dll`.  Or a very near replica of it.  Possibly an automated reverse engineering of it, given the poor choice of variable names.

Comment: @Thunderforge - the function that's shown in full (rather than just as a header) is `GetCurrentProcess` -- the [windows documentation for that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179(v=vs.85).aspx) shows that it is part of kernel32.dll.  [Wikipedia comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_library_files#KERNEL32.DLL) that kernel32.dll mostly just delegates functionality to ntdll.dll, which you can see is exactly what the code shown is doing: it loads a reference to ntdll.dll, finds a pointer to a function from it, then calls it.

Comment: Ouch, so not only do they still run C++, it's still on a MS OS... Trek is actually a dystopia. Who knew?

Comment: Let me get this straight. Destiny runs on Windows?

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba Yup. I look forward to the episode where *Discovery* gets a blue screen of death because Windows has 300 years of legacy code, so they decide to switch to simpler tech (explaining why the *Enterprise* computers ten years later are so "retro").

Comment: ...Which is actually why using a language like C++ makes sense, @Ellesedil.  If the computer is advanced enough that it can turn any arbitrary command into a program to perform said command, it's liable that the compiler is insanely good at optimisation, too.  Thus, since language complexity/learnability is only a minor issue, optimisability becomes the most important factor.  C++ is close to C in terms of raw performance potential, while providing a few features which would be major quality-of-life improvements if the optimiser is writing the program (e.g., templates and exceptions).

Comment: Rust users get triggered by it.

Comment: Not only are thye using C++, they're running Windows.

Answer (score 12):

In Discovery Season 2, Episode 8 (*[If Memory Serves](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/If_Memory_Serves_(episode))*), they talk about

> "...multiple SQL Injections".

It's 2250 and people still don't clean user input.

Comment: Cleaning input is the wrong way to solve SQL injection, anyway. It was 2019 and people still commented that user input should be cleaned!